# Install grpc extension on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: macos, grpc

For 2 days now, I am trying to install grpc for php on my Mac mini server

- Mac OS Big Sur 11.2.1
- Built-in Apache
- I have tried it on php 7.3 and 7.4 installed with homebrew

I have installed grpc `pecl grpc install` after a bunch of attempt I have finally compile and installed it with pecl.

extensions are placed in the good repertory. But I encounter signing issue.
`php -m` show grpc in the list but not `php_info()`

*PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'grpc.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/grpc.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/grpc.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:\n\t/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/grpc.so: code signature in (/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/grpc.so) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapping process is a platform binary, but mapped file is not\n\t/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/grpc.so: stat() failed with errno=1), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/grpc.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/grpc.so.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0*

1. I have disabled SIP. Still same issue.
2. I have codesigned the extension with my apple developper ID. `codesign -f -s "Mac Developer: MY_DEV_ID" /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/grpc.so`
   same issue
3. I have `xattr /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/grpc.so`
   then `sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/grpc.so`
4. I also tried with gatekeeper disabled.

And still the same problem. Is there someone that sucssefully installed grpc on the Mac with Big Sur, who would have an idea on what is going wrong ?

Comment: Note that HTTP/2 over TLS (used by gRPC) is not supported on macOS due to missing ALPN support if Network.framework is being used under the hood. Not sure if this might relate to your problem.

Comment: Note that the 'sudo pecl install gprc' takes a lot of time to compile (> 30 minutes sometimes). I have PHP installed via brew, intalling gprc via brew did not work, but via above command it did. Note you also have to add the extension to you php.ini

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same thing, I have tried several times to install it and I just solved the problem.

In my case when running

```
sudo pecl grpc install
```

there was an error in the installation process with error information like

```
ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.15/pecl/20190902
```

see in the picture:
[running pecl grpc install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zviao.png)

The problem is that the installation process can't create a new directory for /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.15/pecl/20190902, so I tried to create that directory first by running the command:

```
mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.15/pecl/
```

Then run the installation process again and and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

**1. See Cellar/php/... directory:**

*for me:*

[image: look at the directory]

*for you:*

```
ls -la /usr/local/Cellar/php/YOUR_PHP_VERSION/
```

**2. See the directory "pecl" which is a link:**

[image]

**3. Check the link:**

```
ls -la /usr/local/lib/php/pecl
```

**if:**

> No such file or directory

**execute:**

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/php/pecl

sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/
```

**4. Reinstall extension:**

```
pecl install grpc
```